# Docx4J specific text change to image infront text

Tags: bookmarks, docx4j

https://www.programmersought.com/article/6413972878/

I use this site

I create image bookmarkName position
but i want to set image infont

how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean, in Word, "wrapping style - in front of text".

For your w:drawing, try these additional settings:

```
           <w:drawing>
                <wp:anchor allowOverlap="true" behindDoc="false" >
                    <wp:wrapNone/>
```

Use drawing.getAnchorOrInline() to get the Anchor